# Can I add lines of code to execute when I start or reload! a Pry session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry, pry-rails

My main rails app has a MultiTenent feature.  I need to run something like this:

```
MultiTenant.current_tenant = Company.find(9)
```

When I start every Pry session or when I `reload!`.   Can I configure Pry to do this automatically?

Comment: Use a `.pryrc` file? (I don't recall if that re-runs on a `reload!` but easy enough to check.)

Comment: That did the trick for half the question - that works for start-up but not reload.

Comment: redefine `reload!` to also run your code and then call `super`

Comment: Can you throw up and answer to detail how I would redefine `reload!`?